# .NET Core 3.0 Web API won't start in Docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm fresh to Docker, trying to get a proof of concept container running on my machine. I generated a .NET Core 3.0 Web API project using the command `dotnet new webapi`. I've added a controller endpoint that simply returns a string "Hello World."

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DockerHelloWorld.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to successfully build and run this project using `dotnet build` and `dotnet run` respectively.

I am now trying to get this to run in a Docker container. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish --framework netcoreapp3 --configuration Release --output out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerHellWorld.dll"]
```

This is copied and slightly modified from [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/).

I also have the following .dockerignore, just in case it is relevant:

```
bin\
obj\

*.md
*.png
```

I run the following commands:

`docker build -t dockerhelloworldimage .`

`docker create -p 3000:80 --name dockerhelloworldcontainer dockerhelloworldimage`

`docker start dockerhelloworldcontainer`

It seems like each step is being ran based on the output of `docker build`. A hash is returned after `docker create` and "dockerhelloworldcontainer" is returned after `docker run`.

The container stops immediately. I see this by using the `docker container ls -a` command.

`docker logs dockerhelloworldcontainer` has the following output: "It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs. Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from: https://aka.ms/dotnet-download" but I don't really know how to make sense of that.

It's worth mentioning, I got something very similar to this working with a .NET Core 2.2 app.

Any ideas? What could I be missing?

Comment: I see a typo here in the name of the dll `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerHellWorld.dll"]` it should be `DockerHelloWorld` and match your project name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue as @Zied mentioned in the comment, is a typo in the Assembly name you want to call from the  entrypoint command.

If you fix that on the docker file:

```
# All other content remains the same

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerHelloWorld.dll"]
```

You'll get your container successfully started.

> Listing running containers: `docker ps` shows:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                   NAMES
7dcb5c122445        dockerhelloworldimage   "dotnet DockerHelloW…"   5 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp                                    dockerhelloworldcontainer
```

Now, this can look like a misleading error message, but if you try to actually run a wrong dotnet executable from the CLI (not from docker):

```
> dotnet MyNonExistingExeName.dll
```

You'll get the below message:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-.\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\DockerHellWorld.dll does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

I believe that the second and third bullets apply to this case. What that means is that if you have a dotnet executable (or a global/local tool) you can run them with the `dotnet` command so the issue is that your command is being interpreted as a non-existent tool or command and hence the error.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Run the below command to deploy sample Dotnet web API code on docker**

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
COPY ./SampleWebApi3.0.csproj /SampleWebApi3.0/
RUN dotnet restore ./SampleWebApi3.0/SampleWebApi3.0.csproj
COPY . ./SampleWebApi3.0/
WORKDIR /SampleWebApi3.0/
RUN dotnet build "SampleWebApi3.0.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SampleWebApi3.0.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleWebApi3.0.dll"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    sample-web-api:
        build: SampleWebApi3.0/
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8085:80"
```

[Sample web API code 3.0 along with Dockerfile on Github](https://github.com/narottamgoyal/DotNetCore.WebApi.On.Docker)